# Text::Balanced and multiline xml

Tags: xml, perl

Seems like I'm a little bit lost.

I need to parse a large (about 100 mb) and quite ugly xml file. If I use `parsefile`, it returns error (junk after document element), but it would happily parse smaller elements of the file.

So I decided to break the file into elements and parse them. Since parsing XML with regular expressions is discouraged (well I tried it anyway, but I get duplicating results), I tried `Text::Balanced`.

Something like

```
use Text::Balanced qw/extract_tagged/;

while (<FILE>) {
     my $result = extract_tagged($_, "<tag>");
     print $result if defined $result;
}
```

works just fine, so I can extract tagged entries which fit into one line. With something bigger, however

```
use Text::Balanced qw/extract_tagged/;
use File::Slurp;

my $test = read_file("file");
my $result = extract_tagged($text, "<tag>");
print $result;
```

does not work. It reads the file but it can not find a tagged item there.

So the question is how do I extract anything between given tags without `XML::Parser`? And I really really need to avoid chomping it if possible.

P.S. search would return regex guides, heredoc howtos and anything but what I look for

P.P.S. I'm a moron, been trying to parse an invalid file. Still curious how to chop a file if the parser fails though.

---

bvr's answer was close, it really would retrieve some data, but not if the top level tag is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For broken XML, I would try setting [`recover`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Parser#recover) option to [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML). It makes it ignore parsing errors and continue.

Comment: Very Perl way answer: you get what you mean. I'll run the parser with recover mode enabled against the corrupt file and if it manages to extract information I mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Text::Balanced`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aBalanced) for XML parsing is like using a Swiss knife for open heart surgery - *just because you can do it doesn't mean you should.*

If [`XML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aParser) is giving you a hard time, try a newer XML parsing library like [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML) or [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig)

Comment: XML::Twig returns the same error as XML::Parser (which it's based on), and XML::LibXML seems to be too complicated for me so far. I would like to split file into smaller pieces and parse them.

Comment: Ooops. Seems like I'm super stupid. I screwed the file - chopped off the top level opening tag - and was trying to parse corrupted xml. Shame on me! Still wonder how to 'chop' an xml file though, just in case I'll have to deal with corrupted xml files.